# Pagination : How to manipulate only div instead of whole page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm struggling for a problem which might be simple for you but I'm unable to figure it out.

I have a page with products, I also have added pagination to show only 4 products at a time. when i click in second page, it loads the whole page again and show the result. my code for that feature is bellow:

```
<a class="w3-green w3-button w3-hover-green" href="index.php?page=<?php echo $l; ?>"><?php echo $l; ?></a>
```

this works fine but loading the whole **index.php** page again.

What I want is, instead of loading the whole page, is it possible to manipulate/load only the specific **div** which is showing the products. I mean, I want something like: **See the href portion**

```
<a class="w3-green w3-button w3-hover-green" href="#div_id?page=<?php echo $l; ?>"><?php echo $l; ?></a>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe you would have to use javascript alone to achieve this. There is no way to do it in the way you are currently trying to my knowledge

Comment: @Deancoakley thanks for your suggestion. I will consider it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the below link for pagination without page reload.
https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/ajax-pagination-with-jquery-php

demo:https://www.sanwebe.com/assets/ajax-pagination/

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing right now is redirecting to the index.php with different url parameters (which means reloading the whole page).

What you need to do, is to attach a click event (preferably using jQuery) in which you will make an [ajax request](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) to the index.php which will return ONLY the content for that div, and then just replace the content in the div with the response.

Comment: Thanks for your response as it is helpful. I was not aware of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascripts to Load dynamic contents without loading full page.

Ref. links

https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/

https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Comment: That was really helpfull :) Thanks alot